# Can Flutter Ads Run On Window and MacOS

Tags: windows, macos, firebase, flutter, dart

Recently, Flutter announced support for MacOs and Windows. I am just wondering if the banner ads you usually add with Flutter (that work fine on ios and android) are working on MacOs abd windows.

Answer (score 2):

No, not yet. Some packages do work with flutter desktop but [firebase_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) doesn't which is the primary package for integrating ads.
You can check which packages work with Windows, macOS, and Linux here:

- https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?platform=windows
- https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?platform=macos
- https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?platform=linux

Check out official docs for plugin support for Flutter Desktop here:

- https://flutter.dev/desktop#plugin-support

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's compatible with **Flutter Desktop** but found a compatible SDK for desktop.

It allows you to show ads:

- banner
- Interstitial

**The website is called:**
https://adsjumbo.com

**Your SDK is located here:**
https://github.com/AdsJumbo/AdsJumbo.com

**Added a comment asking about Flutter Desktop compatibility:**
https://github.com/AdsJumbo/AdsJumbo.com/issues/39

I hope that more than one has helped you.